# Chromatic index and average degree

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove that $ \frac{|E|}{\lfloor\frac{|V|}{2} \rfloor}\leq \chi '(G)$

This is obvious for graphs where there is an even number of vertices as it comes out to be average degree of a graph, and if chromatic index was lower than it then there would not be enough colors for the edges that are connected with vertex with max degree.

But when |V| is odd, I have no idea.

Comment: See $(8.1)$ of [edge-coloring](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Frederic.Havet/Cours/coloration.pdf).

Comment: I don't see how did they reach those 2 conclusions:" Furthermore, if
a subgraph H of G is odd, then a matching contains at most |V(H)|−1
2 edges. Hence at least
2|E(H)|
|V(H)|−1 colours are needed to properly edge-colour H and thus G."

Comment: And I don't see why did they bring subgraph into this, couldn't they just say that if G is odd then a matching of G contains at most |V(G)|-1/2 edges? I still don't see how was that conclusion reached though

Comment: The edges of one color class in a proper edge-coloring form a matching.
If you have $e$ edges and a matching has at most $x$ edges,
then you need at least $e/x$ colors.

Comment: Yeah, and why does   the matching have to contain |V(H)|-1//2 edges if it's odd? That was the whole point of my question

Comment: The keyword is "at most". This is both in your own first two comments and in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $$\dfrac{m}{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}\leq \chi'(G).$$

As you noted, this is certainly true if $n$ is even, because $\frac{2m}{n}$ is the average degree in $G$ and there has to be a vertex of at least that degree in the graph.

Now suppose that $n$ is odd. Because matchings pair up the vertices, at least one vertex has to be always left out, so any matching in the graph is of size at most $\frac{n-1}{2}$. We know there exists $\chi'(G)$-edge-coloring which gives you $\chi'(G)$ disjoint matchings that include every edge in the graph, we conclude with

$$m \leq \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\chi'(G).$$

Any odd cycle is an example that gives you equality: the average degree is $2$, but you need $3$ colors to make a proper edge coloring.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk I missed your comment above which essentially gives the same answer. Should you want to complete it, let me know and I will remove my post.

Comment: It's fine. The OP still does not seem to believe me. Maybe he believes you :)